# 13.10: how to set accelerator to select keyboard layout rather than switching to next/previous?

Tags: unity, 13.10, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

There is a [host of regressions](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-greeter/+bug/1245268) related to switching keyboard layouts in 13.10. One of them is that the dialogue lets one choose accelerators for selecting previous/next keyboard layout:

[image: screenshot]

Previously, I was able to have accelerator for the **first** layout (which was `Caps Lock`) and for the **second** layout (`Shift+Caps Lock`) rather than changing the layout with either of those combinations.

Someone knows a workaround for this?

PS: A workaround for the Caps LED indicating the layout is likewise appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This command will set layout to the first one:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current 0
```

You can use tweak tools, gnome action, compiz action plugin..etc to create a keyboard shortcut for it.

Layouts are indexed starting from 0. So you can make shortcut for any layout in the list.

You can use this to create complex script for last layout without giving an index:

```
 gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources
```

Like:

```
 gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current $(($(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources | grep -Po "'[[:alpha:]]+'\)" | wc -l)-1))
```